# I can't Change text in the form in React

Tags: reactjs

**I am Learning React and i want to work with forms. Initally i gave value "hello" in the form but i couldn't erase it and type anything in the form.**
import { React, useState } from "react";

```
const App = () => {
  const [num, setNum] = useState(0);
  const handleClick = () => {
    setNum(num + 1);
  };
  const mew = () => {
    console.log("submiited");
  };
  return (
    <div className="bg-green-500 text-center">
      <h1 className="bg-red-200">
         Welcome to <span> Slot Machine game</span> {" "}
      </h1>
      <h1></h1>
      <button
        onClick={handleClick}
        className="bg-red-200 w-92 mt-4 mb-4 rounded-full p-2 text-center"
      >
        Click
      </button>

      <h1>{num}</h1>
      <form className="form" onSubmit={mew}>
        <div className="form-control">
          <label htmlFor="firstName">Name : </label>
          <input
            className="mb-2"
            type="text"
            name="txt"
            value="Hello"
            onChange={(e) => {
              console.log(e.target.value);
            }}
          />
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be work

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './style.css';

const App = () => {
  const [num, setNum] = useState(0);
  const [name, setName] = useState('Hello');
  const handleClick = () => {
    setNum(num + 1);
  };
  const mew = () => {
    console.log('submiited');
  };
  return (
    <div className="bg-green-500 text-center">
      <h1 className="bg-red-200">
         Welcome to <span> Slot Machine game</span> {' '}
      </h1>
      <h1></h1>
      <button
        onClick={handleClick}
        className="bg-red-200 w-92 mt-4 mb-4 rounded-full p-2 text-center"
      >
        Click
      </button>

      <h1>{num}</h1>
      <form className="form" onSubmit={mew}>
        <div className="form-control">
          <label htmlFor="firstName">Name : </label>
          <input
            className="mb-2"
            type="text"
            name="txt"
            value={name}
            onChange={(e) => {
              setName(e.target.value);
            }}
          />
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use **controlled inputs** but not doing that correctly. When using controlled inputs, you feed the value in the input field, and **it is your responsibility to change the value.**

`useState` can help you do this.

```
const App = () => {
  const [num, setNum] = useState(0);
const [textValue , setTextValue] = useState("hello");
  const handleClick = () => {
    setNum(num + 1);
  };
 const changeText = (e) => {
setTextValue(e.target.value);
}
  const mew = () => {
    console.log("submiited");
  };
  return (
    <div className="bg-green-500 text-center">
      <h1 className="bg-red-200">
         Welcome to <span> Slot Machine game</span> {" "}
      </h1>
      <h1></h1>
      <button
        onClick={handleClick}
        className="bg-red-200 w-92 mt-4 mb-4 rounded-full p-2 text-center"
      >
        Click
      </button>

      <h1>{num}</h1>
      <form className="form" onSubmit={mew}>
        <div className="form-control">
          <label htmlFor="firstName">Name : </label>
          <input
            className="mb-2"
            type="text"
            name="txt"
            value={textValue}
            onChange={changeText}
          />
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```